# Hacks to create new instance of rpy2 singleton?

Tags: rpy2

Since Rpy2 can be used in parallel, there should be *some* way to create a new R singleton, otherwise multiprocessing would have caused errors.

Is there a way I can start a new rpy2 instance myself using 
a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `multiprocessing` module lets one achieve parallelism through parallel *processes*. Each such process will run its own embedded R.